# NServiceBus failed to create queue in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, nservicebus, azure-queues

My NServiceBus project would no longer read from Azure Queues.

I deleted them figuring there might be some messages stuck, but now it will no longer create the queues. Note: The same exact code and credentials used to create the queue automatically on its own. Instead I was getting:

> 40400: Endpoint not found..
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.EndSendCommand(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.OnEndSend(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.OnSend(TrackingContext
>   trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 messages, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.Send(TrackingContext
>   trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 messages, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.Send(BrokeredMessage
>   message)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient.Send(BrokeredMessage
>   message)    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Azure.ServiceBus.AzureServiceBusMessageQueue.Send(Byte[]
>   rawMessage, QueueClient sender) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_7\src\azure\Queueing\NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.AppFabric\AzureServiceBusMessageQueue.cs:line
>   179    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Azure.ServiceBus.AzureServiceBusMessageQueue.Send(TransportMessage
>   message, Address address) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_7\src\azure\Queueing\NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.AppFabric\AzureServiceBusMessageQueue.cs:line
>   160    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendSubscribeMessageWithRetries(Address
>   destination, TransportMessage subscriptionMessage, String messageType,
>   Int32 retriesCount) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_7\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line
>   476    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_7(Object
>   state) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_7\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line
>   433    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

My configuration is as follow:

```
using NServiceBus.Config;
using NServiceBus.Config.ConfigurationSource;

namespace XXX
{
    public class AzureConfigurationProvider : 
        IProvideConfiguration<AzureServiceBusQueueConfig>,
        IProvideConfiguration<AzureSubscriptionStorageConfig>,
        IProvideConfiguration<AzureSagaPersisterConfig>,
        IProvideConfiguration<AzureDataBusConfig>
    {
        AzureServiceBusQueueConfig IProvideConfiguration<AzureServiceBusQueueConfig>.GetConfiguration()
        {
            return new AzureServiceBusQueueConfig
                       {
                           QueueName = "XXX",
                           IssuerKey = "XXX",
                           IssuerName = "XXX",
                           ServiceNamespace = "XXX"
                       };
        }

        AzureSubscriptionStorageConfig IProvideConfiguration<AzureSubscriptionStorageConfig>.GetConfiguration()
        {
            return new AzureSubscriptionStorageConfig
                       {
                           ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" +
                                                "AccountName=XXX;" +
                                                "AccountKey=XXX",
                           CreateSchema = true
                       };
        }

        AzureSagaPersisterConfig IProvideConfiguration<AzureSagaPersisterConfig>.GetConfiguration()
        {
            return new AzureSagaPersisterConfig
                       {
                           ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" +
                                              "AccountName=XXX;" +
                                              "AccountKey=XXX",
                           CreateSchema = true
                       };
        }

        AzureDataBusConfig IProvideConfiguration<AzureDataBusConfig>.GetConfiguration()
        {
            return new AzureDataBusConfig
            {
                ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" +
                                   "AccountName=XXX;" +
                                   "AccountKey=XXX"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of NServiceBus are you on?

Furthermore, NSB does not create destination queues,an endpoint only creates the queue that it reads from at startup. After deleting the queue, did you restart the endpoint listening on that queue?

Comment: I am using NSB 3.0.0, could this be the reason why? I was reluctant to update due to the effort involved resolving the dll hell between that and Unity 3.* and other possible breaking changes. I don't recall having modified the NSB instatiation routine to warrant the break. I'm guessing Azure SDK was changed in the last 6 mos necessitating the upgrade - but I could be wrong MS usually tries to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: If you didn't change NSB nor Azure SDK it should not behave differently, nsb should create the queues that it is listening on. Do you know which queue it is that is not created?

Comment: I can also see that it is a subscribe message that fails, is the service that it is subscribing to running? Can you start that first?

Comment: I digged deeper and used fiddler to trace the incoming/outgoing messages you might be right. It kept bombing out autosubscribing to a non-existent queue, that the other process on dev fabric did not have a change to finish and create the queue. IE. Deadlock. Can you help me with the following SO question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843473/condition-when-subscribers-in-nservicebus-send-an-auto-subscribe-message